# Is it okay to use "Sure thing" as a reply to my boss?

Tags: word-usage, formality, business-language

I was wondering whether *sure thing* — when I mean *certainly* — is too casual in a business environment, or whether it could be used under certain circumstances.

(I’m not a native speaker of English.)

Comment: Sure thing is quite casual. If you are fairly new to your particular work setting, it might be good to pay attention to how others talk to your boss, especially those similar to you in terms of tenure and status on the job. Just an opinion.

Comment: Thank you for your kind advice! I will be mindful of how others talk before I use it.

Comment: Based on your parenthetical statement, you might want to check out [ell.se], our sister site.

Comment: J.R.: Thank you for your recommendation. You're right, the site does look more suitable for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways a boss might interpret that remark.

(1) It's too informal; that person should speak more formally.

(2) I like that person's zeal for getting the job done.

This varies from business to business, of course, and even from boss to boss. In general, though, when someone has a reputation for being a top performer who does high-quality work, they can often get away with more informal expressions in the workplace.

If someone works for me, and I know they are dependable and reliable (they get things done right and on-time), then something like *“Sure thing, boss”* is like sweet music in my ears. I know I don't have to worry about the task any longer.

However, if this person's performance is inconsistent – if the person is someone who frequently "drops the ball" – then that same expression might grate on me. Sure, I'll appreciate their enthusiasm, but it will only remind me how much I wish we had someone more dependable on the payroll. Even though it's just an informal expression, you still don't want to assure your boss that something is a *sure thing* unless it is assuredly a *sure* thing!

So, remarks like this depend on a number of factors: the nature of your business, the company culture, your relationship with your boss, your supervisor's temperament, and your own performance and reliability. If you're new at your job, I'd ease into it over time.

Comment: Wow. I really appreciate your thoughtful answer. I enjoyed reading it very much:) I totally understand what you are telling me here. It persuaded me that after all we are all human beings; the way we feel, respond, and think is not so much different from one another even though we use different languages. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

*"Sure thing,"* although informal, is synonymous with *"certainly."* If you and your boss have an informal type of relationship (a good barometer may be if you're on a first name basis with him/her), then you could use it. If you want to respond formally, use "*certainly*." If you're unsure of the accepted etiquette, just use *"yes;"* its meaning is completely neutral and clear.

Comment: I see. It's very informative, thank you! I'll start with "certainly" and maybe I'll try "sure thing" after I build a friendly relationship with my boss:)